# globstar: invalid shell option name on macOS even with bash 4.X

Tags: macos, bash

The new `globstar` option requires `bash 4`. So.. Which `bash` are we on?

```
 $bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Let us try out `globstar` :

```
13:39:28/forecast-fresh $shopt -s globstar
-bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
13:39:32/forecast-fresh $
```

Is there any way to get support for this on macOS?

Comment: You are not testing the bash version of your shell in a reliable way. Do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` right before doing the  `shopt`.

Comment: @user1934428  That's interesting it shows a very different (lower) version

Comment: That's why I said that your way to determine the version does not make sense. It shows the version of the first `bash` executable in your PATH, but not of the `bash` process you are running now. I would as a first step collect all bash executables you have on your disk and check their versions. Then use for your script the one with a sufficiently high version.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Entering `shopt` will get you a list with all bash options which doesn't include globstar for Apple's bash. Probably bash is compiled without support for this option.

To get a bash executable with globstar install brew and brew's bash:

```
brew install bash
sudo bash -c "echo $(brew --prefix)/bin/bash >> /etc/shells"
chsh -s $(brew --prefix)/bin/bash
ln -s $(brew --prefix)/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bash-terminal-app
```

Then change the default shell opened in Terminal to /usr/local/bin/bash-terminal-app and to suppress the ‘Do you want to close this tab?’ prompt when closing windows and tabs, add `-bash` to the list of exclusions.

The new option list is then:

```
$ shopt
autocd          off
cdable_vars     off
cdspell         off
checkhash       off
checkjobs       off
checkwinsize    on
cmdhist         on
compat31        off
compat32        off
compat40        off
compat41        off
compat42        off
compat43        off
complete_fullquote  on
direxpand       off
dirspell        off
dotglob         off
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
extglob         off
extquote        on
failglob        off
force_fignore   on
globasciiranges off
globstar        off
gnu_errfmt      off
histappend      off
histreedit      off
histverify      off
hostcomplete    on
huponexit       off
inherit_errexit off
interactive_comments    on
lastpipe        off
lithist         off
login_shell     on
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion off
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
restricted_shell    off
shift_verbose   off
sourcepath      on
xpg_echo        off
```

—

Under certain circumstances /usr/local/share/ and its subfolders are owned by root (e.g after installing smartmontools, nmap, node etc. with their custom installers) and some of the steps fail. In my opinion it’s safe to `chown -R` the folders to the admin user who installed brew/bash. In my almost vanilla install of macOS and brew, /usr/local/share and /usr/local/share/locale are owned by this admin user.

Comment: I've edited to make it work on both Intel and ARM. Don't understand the need for `bash-terminal-app` though, what is the benefit of this compared to just point Terminal to `$(brew --prefix)/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like install dir for the new version of brew's bash 5 has moved so I needed to do:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bash-terminal-app
exec bash
```

I also had to add it to my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
```

Comment: As written this doesn't answer the question asked. Should this maybe have been an edit to the other answer to point out the differences between Intel and ARM installations of Homebrew?